# Call a subroutine from a DLL in a Fortran program

Tags: dll, fortran

I wish to make use of a subroutine in a DLL for my research. The dll is provided to me as a blackbox and can be used in a leading FE software.

I executed the following code for the dll

```
dumpbin /EXPORTS UDSM_HPS.dll > UDSM_HPS.exports
```

and ended up with the following subroutine

```
2    0 00020D50 _getmodelcount@4
4    1 00020D60 _getmodelname@12
6    2 00020E50 _getparamcount@8
8    3 00020E80 _getparamname@16
10    4 00021AE0 _getparamunit@16
12    5 00001010 _user_mod@124
1    6 00020D50 getmodelcount
3    7 00020D60 getmodelname
5    8 00020E50 getparamcount
7    9 00020E80 getparamname
9    A 00021AE0 getparamunit
11    B 00001010 user_mod
```

My interest lies in the '**user_mod**' subroutine. I created a .lib file from the .def file, by adding 'EXPORTS' in the beginning of the file and isolating the subroutine names, using the following code

```
lib /def:UDSM_HPS.def /out:UDSM_HPS.lib
```

and attached the .lib file to the 'Resourse Files' to my Visual Studio 2013, while placing a copy of my .dll to my 'Debug' folder.

No surprises here, the 'user_mod' subroutine is not seen by the compiler.

Now My question, am I missing something, or is there a differnt way of utilising the subroutine from the dll?

The dll is written in FORTRAN too, and I have written a simple piece of FE code in FORTRAN to run this subroutine.

Long story short: Any assistance is figuring out how to utilise a FORTRAN dll in FORTRAN program is much appreciated.

**Edit 1:**

I am using the Intel Fortran compiler - Intel(R) Visual Fortran Compiler XE 15.0.6.285 [IA-32]. I had tried compiling the same piece of code in Intel(R) Fortran Compiler 10.1.021 [IA-32], but in vain.

The subroutine I intend to call is

```
call user_mod(IDTask, iMod, IsUndr, iStep, iTer,& 
    iEl, Int, X, Y, Z, Time0, dTime, Props, Sig0, Swp0, StVar0,& 
    dEps, D, BulkW, Sig, Swp, StVar, ipl, nStat, NonSym, iStrsDep,&
    iTimeDep, iTang, iAbort)
```

To clarify my rather vague sentence of 'not seen by the compiler', I meant this error

> Error 1    error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol USER_MOD referenced in function PLAXIS_DLL_INTF  interface_files.obj

**Edit 2:**
Thanks for the all the help.
Adding

```
!DEC$ ATTRIBUTES STDCALL,REFERENCE :: USER_MOD
```

was all that was needed to get my code going. Code is behaving like how it should now.

Comment: @124 indicates _stdcall or similar abi is in use so must be specified by the caller.  Lower case without appended underscore differs from typical Fortran defaults so there also you will need to specify your c interface. If it is a 32bit dll your caller must be built in that mode.

Comment: What is your compiler? Intel? Visual Studio is just an editor.

Comment: Can you post the part of the code, where you want to call the subroutine?

Comment: When you say "is not seen by the compiler", exactly what do you mean? What error messages do you get?  The .lib should be added to the Source Files section of the project, though I don't think this matters. More likely, as the others are hinting, you have not declared the procedures with the correct external name and attributes - for example, no mixed case ALIAS. I'm a bit concerned about the lack of a leading underscore in the names without the @, I know that Intel Fortran puts out two names for STDCALL routines for passing them as arguments, but you may be using a version with a bug.

Comment: The compiler I use is Intel(R) Visual Fortran Compiler XE 15.0.6.285 [IA-32].

Comment: The error I get is the error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol USER_MOD referenced in function PLAXIS_DLL_INTF interface_files.obj

Comment: call user_mod(IDTask, iMod, IsUndr, iStep, iTer,& 
        iEl, Int, X, Y, Z, Time0, dTime, Props, Sig0, Swp0, StVar0,& 
        dEps, D, BulkW, Sig, Swp, StVar, ipl, nStat, NonSym, iStrsDep,&
        iTimeDep, iTang, iAbort)
is the part of the code that I used to call the subroutine.

Comment: Because you are putting the lib into your project folder, I assume you staticly link to the dll. Can we see your Interface definition of the function user_mod in your code?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for providing the error message - that is the key. It isn't the compiler that can't see user_mod, it's the linker. Note that the error message refers to USER_MOD, but your dump of the symbols says user_mod. Case matters!

It is also important that the routine you're calling has the STDCALL calling mechanism. This is not the Intel Fortran default, and getting this wrong leads to stack corruption.

The solution is to add the line:

```
!DEC$ ATTRIBUTES STDCALL,REFERENCE :: USER_MOD
```

to the routine calling USER_MOD - in with the declarations. This tells Intel Fortran that USERMOD is a STDCALL routine, and downcases the routine name. Also make sure that you are passing the correct number and type of arguments when you call USER_MOD. If you get this wrong, you'll get link errors. Last, I am guessing about the use of REFERENCE here, but I will assume it is correct since I don't know how USER_MOD was built. At least this will get you past the link error.

Comment: Thanks Steve for the inputs. The program doesn't execute for certain DLLs now.. The error I get, while trying to debug the code is,

' The application was unable to start correctly (oxc000007b). Click OK to close the application'. Am I still missing something here?

Comment: All I can tell you is that code 7B is "The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect." Can you explain further what you mean by "certain DLLs"? What exactly are you trying to do? And how are you debugging - starting the executable under the VS debugger, or something else?